# zsh tab completion bug on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, gnome-terminal

I'm getting a really annoying bug here:

`% git s<TAB>` becomes

```
% git   sgit  s  
send-email   -- send collection of patches as emails  
send-pack     -- push objects over git protocol to another repository  
...
```

It just duplicates the command. If I resize the screen, it goes back to normal: `git s`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your `TERM` environment variable? Which terminal are you using?

Comment: I'm just using the default ubuntu terminal. my TERM is xterm

Comment: What is the default Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Hrm, I can't reproduce that problem on my Ubuntu 12.04 using `gnome-terminal`, `TERM=xterm`, and `zsh`. If you can't _solve_ this problem use `^L` to ask for a terminal re-draw each time it happens. It'll be way faster than resizing the window.

Comment: Yep `^L` does the trick. But I'd like to fix this stupid bug :(

Comment: Should be on Ask Ubuntu website

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it! Darn. It's my prompt

instead of:

`` PS1=$'%B%F{$fg[green]%}${PWD/#$HOME/~}%{$reset_color%}`git-prompt` ${VIMODE} ' ``

I should just do

`` PS1=$'%{$fg_bold[green]%}${PWD/#$HOME/~}%{$reset_color%}`git-prompt` ${VIMODE} ' ``

And everything works fine now...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on macOS, and would like to share how I fixed it.

As far as I can tell, this happens when there is some problem with your custom prompt. I had:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[green]%}%n@%m%{$reset_color%}:%{$fg[cyan]%}${(%):-%~}$reset_color%}$ '
```

And after close inspection, I noticed that the last colour change (`$reset_color`) was incorrectly wrapped. I then changed the prompt like so:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[green]%}%n@%m%{$reset_color%}:%{$fg[cyan]%}${(%):-%~}%{$reset_color%}$ '
```

And I no longer had the issue.