# Zsh tab completion duplicating command name

Tags: macos, zsh, tab-completion, zsh-completion

I'm on OS X Mountain Lion, running the included ZSH shell (4.3.11) with Oh-My-ZSH installed over the top.

When using tab completion with commands such as homebrew, when ZSH lists the available commands, it is also duplicating the command. For example:

```
$ brew {tab}
```

will result in:

```
$ brew brew 
[list of homebrew commands]
```

I'm unsure what is causing this error, as when I resize the terminal window, the first instance of the command name disappears.

If I hit backspace when the duplicates are displayed, I can only delete the second instance of the command, zsh won't let me backspace any further. Also, if I do remove the duplicate with backspace, zsh then acts as if there is no command typed at all.

My .zshrc along with all my other .configuration files can be found at https://github.com/daviesjamie/dotfiles

**UPDATE:** I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146306/) about someone having the same problem on Ubuntu. However, I don't understand the given solution, and I'm not even sure if it applies to my set up?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is likely to arise from misplaced `%{` `%}` brackets that tell zsh that text inside has zero width. The only things that should be enclosed in them are escape sequences that change color or boldness of the text. If you are using new zsh (>=4.3.{unknown version}) I would even suggest to use `%F{color}...%f`, `%K{color}...%k`, `%B...%b` instead of `%{${fg[green]}%}` or what you have there.

The problem with them is that there is no way to query the terminal with a question like “Hey, I outputted some text. Where is the cursor now?” and zsh has to compute the length of its prompt by itself. When you type some text and ask zsh to complete zsh will say terminal to move cursor to specific location and type completed cmdline there. With misplaced `%{%}` brackets this specific location is wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I now understand why it wasn't working; changing the colours to the format you specified fixed the problem perfectly.

Comment: Also, as was my case, doing fancy stuff with the \b character in the prompt will cause the position to be off by 2.

Comment: It appears that in addition to wrapping `${fg[color]}` colors in `%{` `%}` brackets, you also need to wrap `$reset_color` in them.

Comment: This question is also relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/230301/strange-zsh-autocomplete-behaviour and the answer gives an example on replacing the characters correctly. As an amateur, it helped me.

Answer (score 36):

This effect also could be reproduced if you use any of **fancy UTF-8 characters** like arrow, "git branch" character and so on.

Just remove this chars from prompt and duplication will not occur.

Also adding

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8  
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

to `~/.profile can help`

Comment: That was it for me. Any idea how to enable the use of fancy unicode characters without messing up line editing?

Comment: Setting LC_ALL worked for me, but I had to insert  the export instruction inside ~/.zshenv  as it was not picked up from ~/.profile

Answer (score 14):

If you use iTerm on Mac, be sure to check "Set locale variables automatically" in your profile preferences. I had it unchecked for an SSH connection and it resulted in the same bug and I fixed it by leaving that option checked.

Comment: Oh man, it drove me crazy as I forgot I did the same change. Thanks!

Comment: Finally, THIS was what was missing for me. Thanks for mentioning that!

Answer (score 12):

It's an old thread but I faced similar issue in my zsh setup with oh-my-zsh configuration.

Setting `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` fixed the issue.

Comment: This resolved the problem for me with OSx Mojave (10.14.6) and iTerm2.

Answer (score 9):

A lot of answers in a lot of places suggest the `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` solution. This, however did not work for me. I continued to have this issue using oh-my-zsh on both Arch linux and PopOS.

The only solution that worked for me was [this](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/7945#issuecomment-508724741) suggestion by romkatv on an issue on the oh-my-zsh github repository.

It turns out, at least in my case, that the autocomplete duplication issue would only show up if there was a non-ASCII character somewhere on the line (like an emoji). And ZSH would incorrectly assume that this non-ASCII character needs to take up 2 character spaces instead of 1.

So the solution that worked was to open up the `.zsh-theme` file of whatever theme you're using, find all non-ASCII characters and use `%{%G%}` to tell ZSH to only use one character width for that character

For example, the default oh-my-zsh theme `robbyrussel` contains 2 non-ASCII characters. The '➜' character in the prompt

```
PROMPT="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"
```

and the '✗' character in the prompt for git directories

```
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}) %{$fg[yellow]%}✗"
```

Using `%{%G<character>%}` around the 2 non-ASCII characters like this

```
PROMPT="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}%{%G➜%} :%{$fg_bold[red]%}%{%G➜%} )"
```

and this

```
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}) %{$fg[yellow]%}%{%G✗%}"
```

is what finally fixed the issue for me.

So all you need to do is make a copy of the theme file you want to use and edit all the non-ASCII characters as shown above and you should hopefully never see the duplication issue again.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to make both local and ssh work is something like a combination of @Marc's and @neotohin's answers:

1. Set `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` (simply uncomment that part in the template .zshrc; exporting `LC_ALL`, as in @neotohin's answer, instead of `LANG` may also work, I didn't try)
2. **Uncheck** "Set locale environment variables on startup" in the Terminal profile's "Advanced" section (reason: that setting sets `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` instead of `en_US.UTF-8`, which brakes the locale for me in ssh)